# How to stop logging sending message of length in django/python

Tags: python, django

In my settings.py Django project I have my LOGGING dict as

```
LOGGING = {
    'version': 1,
    'disable_existing_loggers': False,
    'loggers': {
        '': {
            'handlers': ['sentry'],
            'level': 'DEBUG',
            'propagate': False,
        },
    },
    'handlers': {
        'sentry': {
            'level': 'DEBUG',
            'class': 'raven.contrib.django.raven_compat.handlers.SentryHandler'
        }
    }
}
```

Now my problem is as soon as I execute
 `logging.debug("hello")`

It prints a message in my console that is

```
b'Sending message of length 781 to https://sentry.io/api/12345/store/'
```

It succesfully logs to sentr but how can I get rid of this message printing in my console?

Comment: You should give your logger a name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The name of your logger is the empty string. This means that it is the "root logger". If you then later use `logging`, you will again use that logger.

You can simply set a name of the logger, for example to `'sentrylogger'`:

```
LOGGING = {
    'version': 1,
    'disable_existing_loggers': False,
    'loggers': {
        # set the name of the logger to a non-empty string
        'sentrylogger': {
            'handlers': ['sentry'],
            'level': 'DEBUG',
            'propagate': False,
        },
    },
    'handlers': {
        'sentry': {
            'level': 'DEBUG',
            'class': 'raven.contrib.django.raven_compat.handlers.SentryHandler'
        }
    }
}
```

Of course if you make a logger later, you should *not* name it `'sentrylogger'`. For example:

```
import logging

logger = logging.getLogger('sentrylogger')

logger.debug('hello')
```

will again yield the same behavior. So as long as you give the logger a different name, or you use the root logger, there is no problem.

Comment: Thanks for the help. But can you tell what was the reason of printing that message?

Comment: @NimishBansal: you trigger the Sentry logger. That happened because the empty string means you made a reference to the *root logger*. By giving a special name, you do *not* use the root logger. If you `logging.debug(..)` you write to the root logger. So that means that you would log both exceptions and simple logging to the sentry logger. By giving a different name, you avoid that.

Comment: oh okay, got it. Thank you very much.